# Java client-server stream initialization

Tags: java, stream, initialization, client-server

I do not really get why the objectOutputStream has to be initialized before the initialization of the objectInputStream within a client class.

If I do not do this way:

`ObjectOutputStream clientOutputStream = new
   ObjectOutputStream(socketConnection.getOutputStream());
ObjectInputStream clientInputStream = new
   ObjectInputStream(socketConnection.getInputStream());`

I will run into a loop.

Is there anybody who can explain it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't run into a loop. You'll run into a deadlock.

Constructing an `ObjectInputStream` reads a stream header that is placed there by constructing an `ObjectOutputStream` at the peer. So if you construct the `ObjectInputStream` first at both ends, both sides are waiting for the other. If you always construct the `ObjectOutputStream` first it doesn't matter what the peer does.